# Nginx Controller Annotations

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, nginx-ingress

I am looking to set the `grpc_send_timeout` on an nginx ingress resource but according the documentation

> On the most recent versions of ingress-nginx, changing these timeouts requires using the nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet annotation. There are plans for future releases to allow using the Kubernetes annotations to define each timeout separately.

, you can use the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet` annotation but on the other section of the documentation I find `nginx.org/proxy-send-timeout` used to set the same config.

which one is currently in use in the latest community ngnix controller?

Comment: Seems easiest to try it and then look at the generated nginx configuration.

Comment: this works ```nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet``` and this is not respected by the controller ```nginx.org/proxy-send-timeout```